# Include the role of Active Record queries in logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, activerecord, multi-database

Rails now includes support for multiple database roles ([by default](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#using-manual-connection-switching), `writing` for the primary and `reading` for the replica):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) do
  # all code in this block will be connected to the reading role
end
```

In development, Active Record queries are logged by default, for example:

```
> User.last
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

How can I include the role used for a query in the logging? For example:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connnected_to(role: :reading) { User.last }
  [role: reading] User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Answer (score 7):

since all query will be logged by the method [log of class AbstractAdapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb#L717) at the finally step, regardless which database adapter you're using: postgresql, mysql,.. So you could override that method and prepend the `role`

```rb
# lib/extent_dblog.rb
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter.class_eval do
  alias_method(:origin_log, :log)
  def log(sql, name = 'SQL', binds = [], 
          type_casted_binds = [], statement_name = nil, &block)
    # prepend the current role before the log
    name = "[role: #{ActiveRecord::Base.current_role}] #{name}"
    origin_log(sql, name, binds, type_casted_binds, statement_name, &block)
  end
end

# config/initializers/ext_log.rb
require File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "extent_dblog.rb")
```

demo

```rb
# config/application.rb
  ...
  config.active_record.reading_role = :dev
  config.active_record.reading_role = :test

# app/models/application_record.rb
 class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.abstract_class = true
   connects_to database: { dev: :development, test: :test }
 end

ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :dev) do
  Target.all
end
# [role: dev]  (0.6ms)  SELECT "targets".* FROM "targets"
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It already helped me observe a problem with my code and fix it. However, it sadly messes with the logging of the method that performed the query. It's systematically logging `↳ config/initializers/extend_dblog.rb:19:in log` (that's where I did put that code in my case). Great for debugging, but not to be used permanently in the code unless this can be helped.

Answer (score 7):

Create a new file  `config/initializers/multidb_logger.rb` with this code:

```rb
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter.class_eval do
  alias_method(:origin_log, :log)
  def log(sql, name = 'SQL', binds = [], type_casted_binds = [], statement_name = nil, &block)
    sql = "#{sql} /* #{@config[:replica] ? 'REPLICA' : 'MASTER'} DB */"
    origin_log(sql, name, binds, type_casted_binds, statement_name, &block)
  end
end

ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.class_eval do
  alias_method(:origin_extract_query_source_location, :extract_query_source_location)
  def extract_query_source_location(locations)
    new_locations = locations.reject { |loc| loc.include? File.basename(__FILE__) }
    origin_extract_query_source_location(new_locations)
  end
end
```

Now in the SQL queries logged by ActiveRecord you are going to see "REPLICA DB" or "MASTER DB" at the end of each query.

This solution use a similar approach to @Lam Phan solution but it preserves all the standard logging behaviour:

- It doesn't log SCHEMA queries
- It correctly display the source file and line from which the query was triggered

Also note that I didn't use `ActiveRecord::Base.current_role` to get the role because it is not showing reliable information (i.e. it prints role `writing` but the query goes to replica DB).

The log can be further customized using the information available in the `@config` hash, such as `host`, `port`, `database`, etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate on when `ActiveRecord::Base.current_role` gives unreliable information and how to reproduce that?